# How to avoid `Pattern not found` message and screen redraw in `less` (as Git pager)

Tags: git, pager, git-config

I just hacked my core.pager to show me more usefull log and diff:

```
[core]
; diff-so-fancy:
;   Seperate files in diff view
; LESS_TERMCAP ... +0 -p ...:
;   Highlight merge commits and file beginnings in diff view (but do not
;   jump because of `+0`), press `n` to jump to the next occurence
; -S:
;   Do not break long lines (useful for log --graph with branches)
pager = "diff-so-fancy | LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\\E[1;37m' less --tabs=4 -RFX +0 -p 'Merge (branch|pull request) .*|^(added|deleted|modified): '"
```

[image: screenshot]

It's quite cool, but I don't like some behaviour of less. How can I prevent

- `Pattern not found` message (for example when running `git diff` on a clean repo)?
- redraw of the full screen (`git log --oneline -5`)?
- the need of pressing `q` even on half screen messages (because of `-S`)?

[image: whitespace bellow log]

Note that if you want to use it without diff-so-fancy, then change `^(added|deleted|modified)` to `^diff --git`.

**A SIMPLIFIED SOLUTION**

```
pager = "diff-so-fancy | GREP_COLOR='1;37' grep --color=always -E 'Merge (branch|pull request).*|$' | less --tabs=4 -RFX"
```

It will only highlight merge commits, does nothing more.

Comment: Those are all questions about `less` itself, rather than about Git. I'm not sure there's an appropriate tag here, or for that matter if that's even really an SO question in the first place, but: to avoid the "not found", don't search; to make less behave nicer on half-page, add `-F` to your options. You already have `-F` so I'm not sure why that's not working.

Comment: @torek: I know that this topic is related to`less`, should I ask on https://unix.stackexchange.com? The half-page issue is caused by `-p` and `+0`.

Comment: Unix.SE might be good. I don't hang out there nearly as much though.

Comment: I just changed the way to highlight merge commits - see the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

> Pattern not found message (for example when running git diff on a clean repo)?

I hacked a solution that inspects the output of `diff-so-fancy` for matches of `commit <SHA>`, `added:`, `removed:`, etc. and only uses `less --pattern` when such matches were found.

https://github.com/agross/dotfiles/commit/8dc82ef2374172b89603f879742900a8499d8372